# Why don't the following expressions trigger "The result of the expression is always false ..."?

Tags: c#

I am playing with the following expressions in VS Code and I noticed there are some cases where VS Code shows warning.

```
if(true==null)
{}
else
{}
```

> The result of the expression is always `false` since a value of type
> `bool` is never equal to  `null` of type `bool?`.

However VS Code does not complain if I write the following.

```
if(new Foo()==null)
{}
else
{}
```

where `Foo` is a class.

## Question

Why don't the above expression produce `The result of the expression is always false ...`?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `new Foo()` always returns non null reference?

Comment: Exotic things like overloaded operators aside, in general the C# compiler doesn't actually try very hard to determine that a condition is always `true` or `false`, just the basics. For instance `int x = 0; if (x < 3) { Console.WriteLine(...); }` with `x` being a local will not trigger any warning either, even if (for example) almost all C compilers would warn.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is exactly where static analyzer tools step in and tell the user "Hey, you're assigning this value to a variable and never changing it. Make it a constant, or just enter the value anywhere you're using it ya ninny!"

Comment: @Logarr: sure, except that compilers perform static analysis by definition, so almost all compilers also detect such things. Dedicated static analysis tools just tend to go a step further and detect things that aren't built into the compiler (for reasons of speed, or because the error is just not common or clear-cut enough to warrant a message if you're not enforcing subjective "best practices"). The C# compiler is unusual here in that it doesn't detect even the simplest cases of using inadvertent constants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First and foremost, *static analysis* isn't perfect, warnings are there as a best effort to protect you from yourself, there are lots of situations where you ***may*** know better.

However, `new Foo()` can still equal `null` ... If someone with dirty little fingers decided to *override* the equality operators :/

Consider the following insidious example:

```
public class Foo
{
   public static bool operator ==(Foo x, Foo y) => true;
   public static bool operator !=(Foo x, Foo y) => false;
}

...

if (new Foo() == null)
   Console.WriteLine("Is null");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Is not null");
```

**Output**

```
Is null
```

However we can use the `is` operator to make sure:

```
if (new Foo() is null)
   Console.WriteLine("Is null");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Is not null");
```

**Output**

```
Is not null
```

Essentially the compiler will convert the above to the following, negating any operator effects:

```
if ((object)new Foo() == null)
```

As pointed out by [@Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) if you are using vanilla Visual Studio or Code this still isn't flagged as always false. Though if you are using Resharper it likely will.

In short, the compiler really only does basic static checks for these types of things, in certain cases it either can't figure it out, or it was decided not to worry about following complex branches to work out if and expression is actually always true or not.

Comment: Although the overloaded operator is a potential situation where the `new` might not be `null`, it's worth pointing out that `new Foo() is null` is still not detected as an expression that is always `true`, so the lack of a warning is not really because the compiler is clever enough to take this corner case into account but because it basically chooses not to bother.

Comment: @JeroenMostert updated and attributed